# If a renter is leaving their apartment and does not know who will be renting it after they leave, can they take their mezuzot?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah, rental

If a renter is leaving their apartment (owned by a non-Jew) and does not know who will be renting it after they leave, can they take their mezuzot?

I have only found discussions when it is known who is moving in--a Jew, a non-Jew, a secular Jew, etc etc. I cannot find anything on what to do when the person leaving has no idea if a Jew or non-Jew will be moving in. I live in the United States, in an area with Jews but not predominantly so.

Answer (score 2):

You clarified in comments that you live in an area with Jews but not predominantly so.

R Yirmiyohu Kaganoff deals with your question [here](http://rabbikaganoff.com/you-cant-take-it-with-you-moving-and-removing-mezuzos/) (see section "You can take it with you")

> [...] the Gemara notes that one who rents from a gentile should remove the
> mezuzos upon leaving (Bava Metzia 102a). The authorities dispute
> whether this is simply permission to remove the mezuzah, or whether
> one is required to do so. **Rav Yaakov Emden (Shaylas Yaavetz 2:121)
> rules that one must remove the mezuzah**, out of concern that the
> gentile will treat it inappropriately, whereas **the Aruch HaShulchan
> (Yoreh Deah 291:3) implies that it is permitted, but not actually
> required**, to remove the mezuzah under such circumstances.

Further down he brings another relevant case

> Beis Lechem Yehudah (Yoreh Deah 291:1) rules that **one should remove
> the mezuzos, even if the gentile landlord usually rents to Jews, as
> long as the next Jewish tenant is not moving in immediately**.

You should nevertheless ask your local Orthodox Rabbi for a ruling specific to your case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, mbloch. Most enlightening. I appreciate it. Shabbat Shalom.